# Grabbing facebook stats with a c# app

Tags: c#, facebook

I have found many examples of getting data from facebook manually.

Is there a way to grab the data using an application (not a web app)?

What we are doing is creating a data repository for our customers so they can look at their data from FB, GA, twitter ect all in one place.

Facebook has me stuck as I can get an authentication code, but none of the URLs such as https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=... will work. Guessing because "me" means I need to be logged into my site for it to work.

Any help/examples would be great. 
Thank You